# neural network object input

Tags: javascript, python, neural-network

I just do some research on neural network. My question is, is it possible to use an input array of numbers and string ?

Here is what I plan to do. I want to make a movie recommendation system that is based on the trending and the personal preferences and NEURAL NETWORK ( I already am done with content-based system and user rating system)

For example, there are 100,000 movies. Each has attribute movieId, mean rating, genre, and tag, popular-rank. Here is data:

```
movieId    meanRate     genre         tag         popular-rank 
1            4.8         action    superhero          4
.........
........
```

the result: `Recommend: 1 for yes, and 0 for no`

*** ask input from user. For example, `genre = music ,  tag = documentation`

```
The actual training: 
[ 4       horror        adult              3 ]  = [ 1 ]     
[ 4.2     music         black hole         6 ]  = [ 1 ]    
[ 4.4     action        foreign            6 ]  = [ 0 ]    
[ 3.7     music         documentation      9 ]  = [ 1 ]
[ 3       music         twist              9 ]  = [ 0 ]
```

The test:

```
[4.8     action    superhero  4 ]  =  [ ??? ]
```

My question is :
  1/ Is it possible to use this approach ?

```
 *** criteria for training: if popular-rank < 3                  => yes
  else if meanRate >= 4 && favGenre == true                    => yes
  else if  meanRate > 4 && favGenre == false                   => no
  else if meanRate < 4 && favGenre == true && favTag == true    => yes
  else if meanRate < 4 && favGenre == true && favTag == false     => no
```

Comment: enumerate strings and you will work only with numbers. Neural network doesn't use `if/else` - you would have to rewrite it as rows with all possible situations so it would be a lot rows.

Comment: `if/else` looks like `Decision Tree` but AI rather use data in rows to build `Decision Tree` without user's access. `if/else` could be also use in [expert system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expert_system) which also is part of AI but probably it rather use languages like [CLIPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLIPS) or [Prolog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog)

Comment: You can use features which are strings. If these strings are discrete, convert them to categorical variables, else, tokenize them or create an embedding for them.